# js changing the css dynamically,

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a mobile version of my page where I have plugged a new iphone like navigation, it is almost working but the background html element is still being shown where it should not.

This is my site: http://www.top-jobs-europe.de/m/

Can someone take a look and try to help me? The purpose is that the menu links should be hidden at first and after opening one should see it, after closing again not. Intuitively you understand my problem once you see the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `iphonemenu.js` file, change the following, add a variable to handle animation of `menu_cose`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menuclose = $("menu_close");
    var pagebody = $("#pagebody");
    var themenu  = $("#navmenu");
    var topbar   = $("#toolbarnav");
    var content  = $("#content");
    var viewport = {
        width  : $(window).width(),
        height : $(window).height()
    };
    // retrieve variables as 
    // viewport.width / viewport.height

    function openme() { 
        $(function () {

            topbar.animate({
               left: "290px"
            }, { duration: 300, queue: false });
            pagebody.animate({
               left: "200px"
            }, { duration: 300, queue: false });
                menuclose.animate({
                   left:"0px"
                },{duration:300, queue:false});
        });
    }

    function closeme() {
        var closeme = $(function() {
            topbar.animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, { duration: 180, queue: false });
            pagebody.animate({
                left: "-90px"
            }, { duration: 180, queue: false });
            menuclose.animate({
                left:"-90px"
            },{duration:180,queue:false});
        });
    }
```

Comment: but look at this: http://media02.hongkiat.com/mobile-navi-with-jquery/demo/index.html
it works even if the js is different

Comment: The difference there is that they are moving the enter `#navmenu` element. You can do that too if you understand the functionality of the iphonemenu.js file.

Comment: i got the typo, i was lost in too many html elements, one div was in a wrong place :), now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, in menucss.css, you could set the `z-index` of `#w #navmenu` to -1?

Comment: not helping, man. any other idea? :(

Comment: Really? Oh, that's a shame. It seems to work in desktop versions of FF, Safari, Chrome and Opera by just changing the z-index at the end of line 7 from 0 to -1.

Comment: really? oh i didnot test it